# How to output script file from remote sever on my php page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on trying to run a script from a remote server and output it to the HTML page using ajax so the user can see. I have tried to do this on my local server with up.sh and down.sh and it works. However, when I put the two scripts on a remote server, start an ssh session and try to get the output from the remote server, it does not show anything, nor does it give me any errors. Am I missing anything? Also as you can see I hard coded the '$gateway' to remoteserver, later I would like to get this value from the textbox field in form.php from user input. What would be the best way to do this?

form.php:

```
    <div id="gatewayInput">
            <form>
                    <input type="text" id="gateway" name="gateway" placeholder="Gateway Name"><br><br>
            </form>
    </div>

<div class="box1">
  <form method="post">
  <label class="col">Up/Down</label>
  <span class="col">
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
    <label for="r1">Up</label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
    <label for="r2">Down</label>
  </span>
    <span class="col">
      <input type="submit" class="button"/>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>


<script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(".button").click(function(event){
             if ((document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value == '')) {
                    alert('Gateway Required!');
                    return false;
             }
             else if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 1) {
                    //console.log("radio button length value: " + document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length);
                    alert('Please Choose Up/Down Value!');
                    return false;
             }
             else {
                    alert('Sucess!');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                            url:"testexe.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()},
                            dataType: "text",
                            success:function(result){
                            $('#div1').html(result)
                            }
                    });
                    return true;
            }
       });
```

testexe.php

```
<?php

include 'res/php/functions.php';
$gateway = 'remoteserver';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';

function cleanInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

//when the submit button is clicked
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
     //$gateway = cleanInput($_POST['gateway']);

      //create the ssh connection
    if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
           ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass);

           if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
                $output = 
                 shell_exec("/tmp/testscripts/up.sh");
           }

           if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 
                $output = 
                 shell_exec("/tmp/testscripts/down.sh");
           }
           //remove  this  if you want to see $output in this file

           echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
     }

} 
?>
```

Comment: `shell_exec` runs commands on the local server - did you mean to use [ssh2_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX that is probably what I need, will I be able to replace shell_exec with just ssh2_exec?

Comment: I don't know. Have you read the online documentation?

Comment: @JaromandaX I got it working now with the ssh2_exec!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the following:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
     //$gateway = cleanInput($_POST['gateway']);

      //create the ssh connection
    if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
           ssh2_auth_password($connection, $gwUser, $gwPwd);
           //mkdir(/tmp/moslehpour/testscripts, 0777, true);
           //ssh2_scp_recv($connection, './aust/conf/hosts', $workDir . '/hosts')
           if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/tmp/user/testscripts/up.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);

           }

           if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/tmp/user/testscripts/down.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
           }

     }


}
```